# Agrupar dados de diferentes tabelas e juntar em um modal os que forem do mesmo grupo

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa tarde! estou tendo um problema em como pensar em algo eficaz.

Possuo duas tabelas: orcamentos e orcamentos_linhas. Na tabela orcamentos_linhas estão alguns itens, ex:

1. Sabão
2. Tintas
3. Sacolas

Todos esses registros possuem o id_orcamento associado á tabela **orcamento**, basicamente a função dela é agrupar todas as linhas da outra tabela. Até ai tudo bem, tudo funciona corretamente!

Eis a dúvida: eu preciso imprimir na tela por "Blocos", ou seja: pegar todas as linhas da tabela **orcamentos_linhas** e agrupar com os valores da tabela **orcamentos** e todos esses valores serão impressos na **div1** (exemplo)
E as outras linhas, associadas com outro registro da tabela **orcamentos** serão impressos na **div2** (exemplo) e assim por diante

O problema é que não estou conseguindo pensar em uma lógica para fazer isso, tentei algumas coisas, mas o resultado final sempre foi imprimir cada linha seguida da outra.
Segue o código que utilizo atualmente:

```
 $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM orcamentos_linha INNER JOIN orcamentos ON (orcamentos.id = orcamentos_linha.id_orcamento AND DATE(orcamentos.data_limite) > CURDATE() ) WHERE cad = ?";  
 $stmt  = $database->prepare($sql_select);   
 $stmt->execute([$user->getCad]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se entendi, mas você está esperando que a consulta no banco de dados retorne uma estrutura de dados hierárquica de forma que você possa acessar os registros de cada orçamento e seus respectivos itens?

Se a questão for essa, está usando o recurso errado. O banco de dados não retornará dados desta forma. Opções:

A) Retornar os dados e agrupar por orçamento.
B) Usar outra estrutura de dados que permita armazenar os dados de forma hierárquica, como por exemplo JSON no MongoDB ou XML.